# Python timedelta spanning DST changeover returns incorrect result?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta

Daylight Savings time began at 2 AM on March 14th, 2021.

Using Python `zoneinfo` to create timezone-aware datetimes as follows:

```
import zoneinfo
from datetime import datetime

tz = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("US/Eastern")

d0 = datetime(2021, 3, 13, 23, tzinfo=tz)
d1 = datetime(2021, 3, 14, 7, tzinfo=tz)
print(d0, d1, (d1 - d0).total_seconds() / 60 / 60)
```

I receive output:

```
2021-03-13 23:00:00-05:00 2021-03-14 07:00:00-04:00 8.0
```

Python is correctly 'seeing' the UTC offset changeover between these values (-5 vs -4), but why would the resulting time delta equate to 8 instead of 7?

For what it's worth, creating the timezone aware datetimes as follows produces the exact same results:

```
d0 = datetime(2021, 3, 13, 23).replace(tzinfo=tz)
d1 = datetime(2021, 3, 14, 7).replace(tzinfo=tz)
```

Comment: Do you get the same result from `America/New_York`? (`US/Eastern` is supposed to be an alias for `America/New_York`.) What does `d0.timestamp()` and `d1.timestamp()` return? (Should be `1615694400` and `1615719600`.)

Comment: Same print results with America/New_York timezone.  Also, timestamps are the expected values you gave.   Crazy, right?  Especially because `(d1.timestamp() - d0.timestamp()) / 60 / 60 == 7` as it should be.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `datetime - datetime`. It could also be in `timedelta.total_seconds`, but I don't think `timedelta` knows anything about time zones.

Comment: Python's `timedelta` arithmetic is wall-time arithmetic - see e.g. [this blog post by Paul Ganssle](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html). A wall clock would include the DST transition in given example, so difference is 8 hours on the clock (11 pm to 7 am). In "reality" it would be 7 hours of course.

Comment: convert to UTC to get the UTC time difference (7 hours for the ex): `print((d1.astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("UTC")) - d0.astimezone(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo("UTC"))).total_seconds() / 60 / 60)` - I'm not gonna say "real" time difference in a physical sense ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion on my original question and per the understanding I gained from the [blog post by Paul Ganssle](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html), I replaced my `timedelta.total_seconds()` math with:

```
d1.timestamp() - d0.timestamp()
```

This gives the proper 'actual' timespan value I was chasing.